# RestTemplate - handle potential NullPointerException when response body is null

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I'm writing client that calls some backend REST service. I'm sending Product object which will be saved in DB and returned in response body with generated productId.

```
public Long createProduct(Product product) {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  final String url = " ... ";

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

  HttpEntity<Product> productEntity = new HttpEntity<>(product, headers);

  try {                                     
    ResponseEntity<Product> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, productEntity, Product.class);
    Product product = responseEntity.getBody();
    return product.getProductId();
  } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    logger.error("Create product failed: ", e);
    throw new CustomException(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), e, e.getStatusCode().value()); 
}
```

This `product.getProductId()` looks like potential NullPointerException if `product` i.e. `responseEntity.getBody()` is null, should I handle it somehow?

I have looked examples over internet of using RestTemplate postFprEntity, getForEntity ... but didn't find any example that handle NPE. I suppose that if body of response cannot be set, it will be some exception thrown and status code 5xx.

Is it possible when response status code is 200, that body can be null?

Comment: yes it is possible. It all depends on what is being sent from the server side

Comment: Ok, thanks. 
But when I make a call to this service using curl or postman, if it returns status 200 there is always body i.e. `Product` json.

Comment: Not sure what is the question here. Let me summarize what I said. body can be null when response code is 200. For handling such cases you need to handle it in your code by checking if it is null. But 5xx exception is thrown if an exception is thrown from server side and not when response is returned with 200 status and body as null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible when response status code is 200, that body can be
>   null?

Yes, it is quite possible and totally depends on the server. Normally, some REST APIs and Spring REST Repositories will return 404 if resource is not found but better safe than sorry.

> This `product.getProductId()` looks like potential NullPointerException
>   if `product` i.e. `responseEntity.getBody()` is null, should I handle it
>   somehow?

Of course you should.

You can check *if* `responseEntity.hasBody() && responseEntity.getBody() != null`. And from there either throw an Exception of your own or handle however you see fit.